# C# User32.dll Нажать и отпустить клавишу в неактивном окне

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть игра в которой пытаюсь имитировать действия игрока, тоесть бег назад бег вперед и т.п
Но если я использую данный код:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);

        int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;

private void StartAFK()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(15000);
                if (enabled == true)
                {
                    int code = 0;
                    switch (code)
                    {
                        case (int)CodeName.MoweToL_W_R:
                            {
                                SendMessage(HWIDL,WM_KEYDOWN,(int)Keys.W,0);
Thread.Sleep(199);
SendMessage(HWIDL,WM_KEYUP,(int)Keys.W,0);
                            }
                            break;
                        case (int)CodeName.Attack_Start:
                            {
                            }
                            break;
                        case (int)CodeName.go_to_Jump:
                            {
                            }
                            break;
                        case (int)CodeName.sit_and_go_mowe:
                            {
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

После данного кода, в игре просто зажимается клавиша W и персонаж бегает постоянно вперед без остановок.
Где проблемма?
Именно данное решение бы подошло чтобы окно оставалось не активным и в трее.

Comment: Не панацея, но все же, вы пробовали класть сообщения в очередь?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message Loop штука тонкая и морозить UI поток - значит негативно влиять на обработку Windows сообщений. Многие Windows сообщения обрабатываются через цепочнку приложений, и зависание UI потока в вашем приложении может просто приморозить чужое приложение. Да, такое бывает, особенно в старых приложениях. Поэтому давайте асинхронно.

Так же для отправки клавиш стоит использовать `PostMessage`.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern uint MapVirtualKey(Keys uCode, uint uMapType);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);
```

Получится такой метод:

```
const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const uint WM_KEYUP   = 0x0101;

// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup
public static void WMSendKey(IntPtr hwnd, Keys keyCode, bool isDown)
{
    uint scanCode = MapVirtualKey(keyCode, 0);
    uint lParam = 0x00000001 | (scanCode << 16);
    if (!isDown)
        lParam |= 0xC0000000;
    PostMessage(hwnd, isDown ? WM_KEYDOWN : WM_KEYUP, (uint)keyCode, lParam);
}
```

Как видите, правильное формирование сообщений `WM_KEYDOWN` и `WM_KEYUP` немного сложнее, чем у вас реализовано. На самом деле, я уже [публиковал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1360673/373567) здесь этот метод ранее, вы просто не нашли.

Итого получится

```
private CancellationTokenSource _cts;

private async void StartAFK()
{
    try
    {
        using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(15000, _cts.Token);
                CodeName code = (CodeName)0;
                switch (code)
                {
                    case CodeName.MoweToL_W_R:
                        WMSendKey(HWIDL, Keys.W, true);
                        await Task.Delay(199);
                        WMSendKey(HWIDL, Keys.W, false);
                        break;
                    case CodeName.Attack_Start:
                        break;
                    case CodeName.go_to_Jump:
                        break;
                    case CodeName.sit_and_go_mowe:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    _cts = null;
}

private void StopAFK()
{
    _cts?.Cancel(); // это ведёт к практически немедленной остановке цикла, даже 15 секунд ждать не надо
}
```

Асинхронный подход дает еще один ощутимый плюс: интерфейс приложения не зависает.